# Datatable Search Filter Column problem "mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Tags: laravel, datatables

I want to make a Prescription management system with laravel. so need to patient list. i loaded patient information in Datatable. this is loaded successfully but when i use Datatable Search Filter Column  then this error message come "mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

```
  var table = $('#patient-data-table').DataTable( {
    "processing":   true,
    "serverSide":   true,
    "paging":       true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching":    true,
    "ordering":     true,
    "info":         true,
    "autoWidth":    false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [1] }],
    "ajax": {
        "url":      "{{URL::to('/')}}/patientList",
        "type":     "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
    },    
    "columns": [
        {
        "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
            return '<img src="{{asset('patient_image')}}/'+JsonResultRow.image+'" style="height:30px; width:30px; border-radius: 30px;"/>';
        }
        }, 
        { "data": "fullName" },
        { 
         data: {fullName : "fullName", email : "email", address : "address"},
         mRender : function(data, type, full) {
            return "Name: "+data.fullName+' <br> '+"Email: "+data.email+' <br> '+"Address: "+data.address; 
          } 
        },

        { "data": "contact_number" },
        { "data": "gender" },
        { "data": "Link", name: 'link', orderable: false, searchable: false}      
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
  } );
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: try to dump the data given in the table

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
{ 
  data: {fullName : "fullName", email : "email", address : "address"},
  mRender : function(data, type, full) {
    return "Name: "+data.fullName+' <br> '+"Email: "+data.email+' <br> '+"Address: "+data.address; 
  } 
},
```

For:

```
{ 
  data: {fullName : "fullName", email : "email", address : "address"},
  mRender : function(data, type, full) {
    return "Name: "+data.fullName+' <br> '+"Email: "+data.email+' <br> '+"Address: "+data.address; 
  } 
searchable: false, //add this line
},
```